# a node to restrict a point cloud range

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS node  that can republish a point cloud in a restricted range or at  generation time from a depth map restrict the resulting cloud to a range.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277582/a-node-to-restrict-a-point-cloud-range/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [wiki/pcl_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros), especially the filter nodelets it provides.

It's not documented on the wiki page, but there is a `CropBox` filter ([nodelet xml here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/f81cded18b4f6d398b460a36c953fe6620a02bd6/pcl_ros/plugins/nodelet/libpcl_ros_filters.xml#L38-L42)) that does exactly what you are after.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
First, you can subscribe the topic \scan and then publish it again with the same message type with a different topic.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2017-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1